# Keyboard is not visible in textbox of webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I am opening web view in dialog box, when i open website inside the keyboard is not visible

here is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Title here");

final  WebView wv = new WebView(this);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        return true;
    }
});

wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
            }
        return false;
    }
});

alert.setView(wv);
wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
alert.show();
```

**Update**

Have tried with `requestFocus` it does not work. Will keyboard not work when web and dialog combined? how Facebook login dialog shows keyboards?

is there any method to open a web site in pop and keyboard should work there !